# Toolbar achievements has stopped to expose button informative badges

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

On the right part of the top toolbar, there are 4 icons representing inbox messages, achievements, review queues and community expandable menu.

I have noticed days ago an issue that the achievements stopped to show the red circle/green rectangle informing of reputation loss/gain and for badges.

I think I have unconsciously turned it off somewhere because the messages inbox still works correctly. Is there a settings page where I can turn it on?

Comment: You are still at a net negative since you placed your bounty (at -1, in fact). The achievements dialog only lights up for net positive changes. Next upvote on a post should start showing again.

Comment: Post it an answer please. I didn't know it is related to bounty. It makes a perfect sence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted a bounty a few days ago, and you are still in the net-negative reputation:

- Aug 29: -50, then +2, +10, +10, leaving you at net -28.
- Aug 30: +5, leaving you at net -23
- Aug 31: +2, leaving you at net -21
- Sept 1: +10, +10, leaving you at net -1.

The achievements icon only shows up when there is a net positive reputation change to report. You have another accept or upvote to go before you are in the plus again.